# Where are JavaScript exceptions displayed when using Android WebView?

Tags: android, exception, webview

I have this simple HTML that I load into an Android WebView (SDK version 1.5)-

```
<html>
<body onload="nomethod()">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Function nomethod() doesn't exist but the LogCat doesn't display any error.
It seems that any exception that isn't caught cannot be traced.
Any idea how can I handle or trace uncaught exceptions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to get that if you register a `WebChromeClient` with your `WebView`. In particular, look at `onConsoleMessage()`.

Comment: That would explain why I didn't remember it... :-)

Answer (score 0):

They *aren't* displayed unless you've registered a client. Since you're unable to use it, you and your users will never see JSExceptions.