# Which Android tablets are usable for testing Javascript heavy web applications

Tags: javascript, android, html, tablet

I need to develop a client heavy web application that works on Android tablets. It must work with the default browser and maybe as PhoneGap application. So I need a tablet for testing.

[Previously I have had really bad experiences with Android browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931033/how-can-i-know-if-a-javascript-exception-occurred-in-a-phonegap-application-and). My HTC Desire Z does not show JavaScript exceptions in Android LogCat. If an exception occurs it just dies silently and there is no way to tell what raised the exception.

So what Android tablets are known to show the exceptions? Stack traces would be awesome, but my hopes are not very high.

I know that console.log messages can be read using [weinre](http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/) or [jsconsole](http://jsconsole.com/), but those alone does not help with the exceptions.

In short I just want someone to confirm that you can see messages about uncaught Javascript exeptions of the default browser in device X.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think this answers it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230899/where-are-javascript-exceptions-displayed-when-using-android-webview

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Not really. That does not apply to the stock browser. I  think PhoneGap already does that (and it does not work on that phone). Also I'm asking about specific devices. Not how to write webviews.

Comment: Maybe take a look at `about:debug`? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/android-browsers-aboutdebug-what-do-those-settings-do

Comment: Maybe I still don't understand, but it DOES apply to the stock browser (webkit) and the same browser exists on all the devices (as long as they're 2.1>).

Comment: Actually, no tablet is guaranteed to have the same browser. That depends on the tablet manufacturer and what they changed to get the tablet out there. However, it must be said that **most** manufacturers have not implemented a different browser in anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I can now confirm this on two devices. Asus Transformer TF101 (Andoid 3.2.1) and Samsung Galaxy Tab 10" P7500XXKG7 (Android 3.1) does log Javascript expections in adb logcat!

The log entry is following

```
E/browser ( 1245): Console: Uncaught Error: mn virhe http://jsbin.com/ihirut:23
```

Great!

But when it comes to being usable for Javascript heavy web apps these both tablets suck a big time! Both seem to have a **huge performance regression** in HTML5 Canvas drawing performance. My phone, HTC Desire Z, which has a much slower processor and has an older version of webkit in the browser is **much** faster than these tablets!

It appears that Google or the manufacturers has screwed up with the hardware accecelaration. More information here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17458

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1213087

You can workaround this issue by using Phonegap which does not currently enable the hardware accecelaration.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, your searching for a tablet which has those exceptions in it.
I know this of a friend of my which has the same problem on some heavy javascript sits.
Hes using the Acer Iconia A500.

I hope it was that what you searched. For debuging i refer to this post:
[Hidden Debuging Tool Android Browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/android-browsers-aboutdebug-what-do-those-settings-do)

Have a nice day

safari

Answer (score 0):

The Opera Browser said that it has cross-device debug, Maybe it's suitable for you to debug.

Opera Dragonfly 1.1[Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/)

Comment: I'm aware of this, but this does not help with the default browser.